# how to update another operation with the values obtained from the result set using while loop?

Tags: java, mysql, for-loop, while-loop, resultset

Here is my java code:

```
public int function(String name)
{
    int i=0;

    int id=0;


    try
    {
        String get_id="SELECT id FROM table_name JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_name.pk_id = tbl_2.fk_name_id where active_flag=1 and updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE";

        Statement stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(get_id);

        while (rs.next())
          {
             id= rs.getInt("id");

             String update="UPDATE table_name SET active_flag=NULL WHERE id="+id+"";    
             stmt.executeUpdate(update);
          }


        i=1;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println(e);
    }


    return i;

  }
```

while running this, I am getting SQL Exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

---

Please help me to perform this operation in an alternative and simple way. I just want to update the same table with the value obtained from first SQL Query, as there is n number of values in
table and the value change dynamically, I used while loop. please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not you use single sql query `UPDATE table_name SET active_flag=NULL WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_name JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_name.pk_id = tbl_2.fk_name_id where active_flag=1 and updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)`?

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tbl_driver' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I can't see `tbl_driver` alias in your query or my example query. You may need to look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188002/error-1093-hy000-you-cant-specify-target-table-a-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: sorry i am using different table name here from my real table name. the rest are same

Comment: Other way you can do is get the data from resultset and store it a map and later iterate the map and update the table but the best way is subqueries

Comment: this is my actual code i just use now,: "UPDATE tbl_driver SET active_flag=NULL WHERE Pk_driver_id = (SELECT * FROM tbl_driver JOIN tbl_location ON tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id WHERE updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND active_flag=1);"  "ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)" how to overcome this error? please help

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the update sql statement to:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET active_flag=NULL 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 
        NULL 
    FROM 
        table_name as tbl
        JOIN tbl_2 
            ON tbl_name.pk_id = tbl_2.fk_name_id 
        where tbl.active_flag=1 
        and tbl.updated_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
        AND tbl.id=table_name.id
)
```

Comment: i need to "UPDATE table_name 
SET active_flag=NULL" for columns with specific Id in table

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tbl_driver' for update in FROM clause

Comment: tbl_driver is the actual table name that i use instead of table_name in my actual query